# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction in Eclipse

Tags: jpa, rollback

I'm trying to create an application in JPA using Eclipse . the UML model of the application is the following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5PTo.png)

And I have the error in class called "GRADETEST.java" in the function shouldSaveGrade() .
In this function I create variable grade final var grade = Fixtures.createGrade(subject).
before doing this I initialize a variable called subject which is fictitious . So when I do Junit test it crashes at the line
"entityManager.getTransaction().commit();"

I send to you Grade , subject , GRADETEST ,SubjectTest classes .
I'm new in this domain so I don't know why does this error appears .

```java
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.repository.GradeTest.shouldSaveGrade(GradeTest.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:65)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1402)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3285)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Intégrité référentielle violation de contrainte: "FKEP37YMUXQE45LFAYSRIMBRS2A: PUBLIC.GRADE FOREIGN KEY(SUBJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SUBJECT(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKEP37YMUXQE45LFAYSRIMBRS2A: PUBLIC.GRADE FOREIGN KEY(SUBJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SUBJECT(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into Grade (subject_id, gradevalue, weight, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-210]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:527)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:227)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:203)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:311)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:252)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:1177)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:1195)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:188)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:135)
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:61)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:174)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 90 more
```

```java
//GradeTEST
package fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.repository;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.repository.api.GradeRepository;
import fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.repository.api.SubjectRepository;
import fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.model.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
class GradeTest extends Base {

    GradeRepository gradeRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void before() {
        gradeRepository = daoFactory.newGradeRepository(entityManager);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void after() {
        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void shouldSaveGrade() {
        // TODO
    
        
         final var subject = Fixtures.createSubject();
         subject.setId((long)1);
        subject.setName("Math");
        subject.setHours((float) 5.0);
         // Create a date object
        Date d = new Date(2022,2,28);
        subject.setStart(d);
        subject.setPoints(5);
        subject.setEnd(d);
         final var grade = Fixtures.createGrade(subject) ;
         
         entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
         gradeRepository.save(grade);
         entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
         entityManager.detach(grade);
         
         var pGrade = gradeRepository.findById(grade.getId());
         assertThat(pGrade).isNotNull().isNotSameAs(grade);
         assertThat(pGrade.getValue()).isEqualTo(grade.getValue());
         assertThat(pGrade.getWeight()).isEqualTo(grade.getWeight());
    }
```

```java
//Grade
package fr.uga.im2ag.l3.miage.db.model;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
//@Table(name="Grade")
// TODO ajouter une named query pour une des requÃªtes Ã  faire dans le repository
public class Grade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id") 
    
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Subject subject;
    
    @Column(name = "gradevalue")
    private Float value;
    private Float weight;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public Grade setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        return this;
    }

    public Float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Grade setValue(Float value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public Float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public Grade setWeight(Float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
//Subject
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.util.Date;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Subject")
// TODO ajouter une named query pour une des requÃªtes Ã  faire dans le repository
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name = "id",nullable=false) 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer points;
    private Float hours;
    private Date start;
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date end;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Subject setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Subject setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public Subject setPoints(Integer points) {
        this.points = points;
        return this;
    }

    public Float getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public Subject setHours(Float hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
        return this;
    }

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public Subject setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
        return this;
    }

    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public Subject setEnd(Date end) {
        this.end = end;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKEP37YMUXQE45LFAYSRIMBRS2A: PUBLIC.GRADE FOREIGN KEY(SUBJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SUBJECT(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement: insert into Grade (subject_id, gradevalue, weight, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`

Here **Grade** is dependent on **Subject**
and you're trying to save Grade without saving Subject

It'll work if you just save Subject

as **Subject** and **Grade** have a relation; it'll save **Grade** as well